# HTML 5 Color Input: Define Custom Colors

Tags: html

I understand the color input currently only works with Opera & Chrome, but it would still be a great time saver if I could define a custom color set that would at least save when I close the browser, or preferably be defined by the website itself.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is possible using the `list` attribute.

Example:

```
<input type=color list=colors>
<datalist id=colors>
<option value=#ff0000>
<option value=#ffff00>
</datalist>
```

I'm not able to test it in chrome, but at least in opera the dropdown menu shows only red and yellow -- as specified in the `datalist` element.

Comment: I've just read that it will be supported in Chrome 23. But until Chrome 23 is released, I think you have to use Opera.

Comment: At least someone's put it in, though I'm surprised FF don't have it. thanks Matthias